# asp.net core 2.2 posting file results in http/415 unsopported mediatype

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2, http-status-code-415

From postman I'm trying to post a file to an asp.net core 2.2 api-controller.

```
POST /api/epd/noshow/uploadfile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44361
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3d633228-2554-442b-84f4-4e8214972886,a8f994f4-973e-411f-b96b-778af2c082b4
Host: localhost:44361
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------201375848683546790642901
content-length: 237
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="C:\temp\caldr.json


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

The api-controller method

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult UploadFile([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I've already tried FromForm, FromBody, nothing. Setting content-type in postman, not setting the content-type in postman always returns the same error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why did you set a header of `content-type` that specifies `boundary` as `--------------------------201375848683546790642901` while setting another header of `Content-Type` that says the boundary is `----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and solution. Just for reference if someone else encounters the same mind boggling problem.

On the 'grandmother' class of the controller, there is the following attribute :

```
[Consumes("application/json")]
```

of course form-data was not accepted :-)

override this default behaviour by adding the following attribute to the action

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simple than expected :) You to send the request body in a form data. Here, this example shows only the simple file post call with ASp.NET Core 2.2 - WebAapi

Postman:

[image]

API:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I did in postman. But still is not working. Some configuration in the pipeline that I should add ?

Comment: Please see the code change, you have to remove `[FromForm]` form the request method @BrilBroeder

Comment: Removed the FromForm still no success. It even does not hit the constructor of the controller. I thought maybe a routing problem. So I changed to GET, removed the body and it does hit the controller/action. Changed back to POST, added file and it hit the action but no file in it. I noticed I forgot to set the 'key' in postman. Setting the key, and again it does not hit the controller constructor :-(

Comment: @BrilBroeder, That sounds like [XYproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: :-) no it is not. I just want to upload a file and from there on process that file.

Comment: Start with a clean template; check that works for you. If that will work, your issue is diffrent than what you're trying for @BrilBroeder

Comment: I did and It works, but when I switch to this controller it does not. Why ??? That is what I'm trying to figure out.